# Adding from one group, to another, then deleting the original group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-membership

I have groups, group1 and group 2, ranging from A to Z...
group1-A, group2-A, group1-B, group2-B

I'd like to run through and script is so it takes every member from group1-A, adds them to group2-A, then deletes group1-A [without stopping for confirmation].

I currently have a cmd pipe that will add from one group to another.  then i run another to delete the original group, then hit y to confirm.  I then up arrow 2 times, and change the letter of the alphabet, and re do..

```
get-adgroupmember group1-A | foreach { add-adgroupmember -identity group2-A -members $_
```

then

```
remove-adgroup group1-A
```

then Y to confirm.

Any way I can throw this so it just iterates through evevery group from A to Z, adds, then deletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try it myself but you can do something like :

```
0..25 | % {[char]($_+65)} | % {$a=$_;get-adgroupmember group1-$a | foreach { add-adgroupmember -identity group2-$a -members $_ }; remove-adgroup group1-$a -force}
```

The first two pipes are generating letters from 'A' to 'Z' then % is an alias for the `Foreach-object` Cmdlet.

Comment: thanks for the reply...ill have to look through some syntax as Im not sure what those first two pipes are doing.

Comment: @JCGee Iadd an explanation for the two pipes.

Comment: I see.  So can't iterate over letters, the +65 gives each letter's ASICS equivalent, the tour cats it to a character.    Thank you JP.